# Why is there no minimum size of bool data type?

Tags: c++, boolean

I was reading C++ Primer and came across a table containing the  minimum guaranteed size of data types of C++, in that it was  written that the minimum size of bool is not guaranteed.
Is there any specific reason for it?

Comment: It is not a duplicate, I am not asking why is the size of boolean 1 byte, I am just asking why isn't there a minimum size of a boolean.

Comment: *All* data types are at least one byte.

Comment: @KeithThompson  All data types are 1 byte is automatically guaranteed, because the smallest addressable unit of memory is 1 byte.

Comment: @ps06756: Which is sufficient for `bool`, so why bother stating that minimum size again?

Comment: @MSalters Because, if the book is not mentioning the minimum size of bool, then there is a reason for it.

Comment: Author. must have also known this fact, so if he is mentioning minimum size of all types except bool, there has to be a good reason for it.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, a boolean's size need only be a single bit but in memory allocation, types need to be aligned in a way to be compatible with other types and filler bitsare sometimes used on different compilers and computer architectures so that the smallest capsule to store any data type is a byte.

[Why is a boolean 1 byte and not 1 bit of size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626815/why-is-a-boolean-1-byte-and-not-1-bit-of-size)

As per the last comment, I should add this quote from the Wikipedia article on byte:

The byte /ˈbaɪt/ is a unit of digital information in computing and telecommunications that most commonly consists of eight bits. Historically, the byte was the number of bits used to encode a single character of text in a computer[1][2] and for this reason it is the smallest addressable unit of memory in many computer architectures.

Comment: Don't forget that a variable of type `bool` also have to be addressable (using e.g. the address-of operator `&`) which also means it has to be at least the smallest addressable unit of the system, which usually is a byte.

Comment: In C++, "byte" is synonymous with "char" and is defined as the smallest addressable unit of memory.

Comment: You should quote relevant parts of the C++ and/or C standard, because I cannot find anything in the former that guarantees one byte for a `bool`. The question is why the minimum size it *not* guaranteed.