# tilde operator returning -1, -2 instead of 0, 1 respectively

Tags: c++, boolean, tilde

I'm kind of puzzled by this. I thought the ~ operator in C++ was supposed to work differently (not so Matlab-y). Here's a minimum working example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    bool banana = true;
    bool peach = false;
    cout << banana << ~banana << endl;
    cout << peach << ~peach << endl;
}
```

And here's my output:

```
1-2
0-1
```

I hope someone will have some insight into this.

Comment: What did you expect? That's bitwise inversion of the [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) representation of the value stored in memory.

Comment: `~` is the binary-not operator, so binary all zeroes becomes binary all ones, and so on.

Comment: @leemes, I expected the ~ operator to flip true to false and vice versa, and for some reason I thought I remembered using it that way in the past. It seems that ~ operates on the whole byte though - my bad.

Comment: @castle-bravo I first read your question a bit wrong, namely I thought you apply the operators to integers. Then, a boolean inversion wasn't very "logical" to me as an expectation, so I didn't know what you expect. Now that I notice that you saw it like "inversion of a boolean value" it makes totally sense to me how you interpreted it! And I admit, it can be confusing. :)

Comment: @leemes, The way that I phrased the title of the question was probably what caused you to misunderstand my meaning.

Comment: Exactly. I only looked at the title, should have looked more carefully. My bad ;)

Comment: [Why is a boolean 1 byte and not 1 bit of size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4626815/608639)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is exactly what should happen: when you invert the binary representation of zero, you get negative one; when you invert binary representation of one, you get negative two in two's complement representation.

```
00000000 --> ~ --> 11111111 // This is -1
00000001 --> ~ --> 11111110 // This is -2
```

Note that even though you start with a `bool`, operator `~` causes the value to be promoted to an `int` by the rules of integer promotions. If you need to invert a `bool` to a `bool`, use operator `!` instead of `~`.

Comment: and that after the execution of the `~` operator the value is no longer interpreted as `bool`.

Comment: This makes everything crystal clear to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

~ is bitwise NOT operator which means it flips all the bits. For boolean NOT, you should be using ! operator