# Custom length bit types in Go?

Tags: go, types, bit

In Go is it possible to define a custom type with a number of bits other than those offered by `byte uint uint16` or any of the other built-in types?

I'm planning on using "just enough bits" to represent variables and wanted a 6-bit and a 4-bit type. Perhaps a composite bool type?

```
type fourbit struct{
    ones   bool
    twos   bool
    fours  bool
    eights bool
}
```

Though this sort of thing is quite messy and it would be nice to have a more general solution for n-bit types.

Comment: You might be looking for something like this; https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/ you can store small values as a byte, not so sure about storing values that are one and a half bytes, you'll probably have to round up and put it in a 2byte buffer.

Comment: A more common pattern in most programming languages (and used throughout Go) is a bitmap to hold up to 8 values per byte: http://play.golang.org/p/DZj9FerK19

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The minimum size of a Go type in current implementations, including type `bool`, is one byte, .

References:

[The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)

Comment: [_basic addressable unit_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4626993/2055586), interesting, very cool thanks for the quick reply.